# Determining whether a string has a substring (word)

Tags: javascript, string

I try to use a conditional to verify if a string contain a certain word, for example:
I want to use a method (regex?) to find if a string has the text `"&SWE>clickable"`.

```
var text1 = "layer_legs";
var text2 = "layer_head&SWE>clickable";

if (....)
   document.write ("the layer is clickable")
else
   document.write ("the layer is not clickable")
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`String.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf). It returns -1 if the string is not found, otherwise it returns the index where the string was found. You can use it like this:

```
if (s.indexOf("&SWE>clickable") !== -1) { ... }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 if (text2.indexOf("&SWE>clickable") > -1) {
    ....
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (/&SWE>clickable/g.test(text2)) {
    // exists
}
```

---

EDIT: Using indexOf like others have posted might be better, since it’s more readable and you don‘t need to escape characters. And arguably faster :/

Comment: Your regexp should be in parentheses, do u think so ?

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
if (text1.indexOf('&SWE>clickable')>=0){ ... }
```

or regex way :

```
var re = new RegExp('\&SWE\>clickable')
if (re.test(text1)){ ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 if(text1.indexOf(text2)) 
    document.write ("the layer is clickable") 
 else 
    document.write ("the layer is not clickable")
```