# Find word with regex in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I find a word with regular expression in Javascript?

For example:

```
http://127.0.0.1/w/?id=2&tab=wow
```

I want to know if this link contains the word 'tab'.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Determining whether a string has a substring (word)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7639650/determining-whether-a-string-has-a-substring-word)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var string = 'http://127.0.0.1/w/?id=2&tab=wow'
var containsTab = string.indexOf('tab') > -1
```

Or if you really want to use a regex:

```
var containsTab = string.match(/tab/);
```

Comment: Tab could be contained in a string and still return an index of zero. `indexOf()` returns `-1` for not-found.

Comment: Since this is an accepted answer, please update your regexp to include word boundaries, like this `/\btab\b/`. This is so that words like `stable` do not trigger a match.

Comment: @Marko - the OP didn't mention anything about NOT finding the word stable.

Comment: @jahroy - In fact he was pretty clear by asking for `word` and not a `substring`. (Maybe he even wanted to know whether there is a query string parameter named `tab` but didn't ask properly; I'm not going into that.)

Answer (score 1):

1. jQuery is not a language. It's a library written for JavaScript.
2. You don't need a regular expression.
3. Use `indexOf`.

   ```
   var str = 'http://127.0.0.1/w/?id=2&tab=wow';

   if(str.indexOf('tab') > -1) {
       // Contains string
   } else {
       // Doesn't
   }
   ```

Comment: Does the string `stable` contain the **word** `tab`? In your case, yes. And this is obviously wrong answer.

Comment: @MarkoDumic: Yes, `stable` does contain the word `tab`.

Comment: The OP mentions nothing about exluding stable.