# in Javascript how to find word using regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to recognize all words that have  similar pattern  ($"????" ) 
i.e

1. `$"ahmad"`
2. `$"kokoasddsf"`
3. `$"asdasd asdas"`

but not
`$asdasd`
nor 
`$"asdasds`

Comment: JavaScript regular expression fundamentals are available in a lot of places. Here are a few links:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp

and...

http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/redev2.shtml

Comment: check this [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10422660/find-word-with-regex-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex expression:

```
/\$"[a-z ]*"/i
```

Comment: THank you dude, 
I have another question  is't possible to replace $"Ahmad" with Ahmad (wizout the $ and "")  using replace js function

Comment: @AhmadSaadFares Post a new question and I'll answer it