# How do I return tweets with a certain hash tag with this JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex, twitter

```
filter: function(t){ return  /^@\w+/.test(t.tweet_raw_text); },
```

If this JS returns tweets that start with an `@` symbol, how to do return tweets with a specific hash tag, or word in them?

Everything I try just breaks it! It originates from this JS:

http://tweet.seaofclouds.com/

Comment: If you want quick help, post your best attempt at doing that youself so that people can help you fix it.

Comment: *"Everything I try just breaks it!"* What exactly did you try? You have to test whether the tag is in the text, which is pretty straightforward and has already been asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7639650/determining-whether-a-string-has-a-substring-word

Comment: It's obviously this section here but can't figure out the regular expression: /^@\w

Comment: I think I've also closed off my unanswered questions now

Comment: Look at the link I posted in my previous comment. You don't necessarily need regular expressions for this. You could do `str.indexOf('#' + tagname)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank your the above reply - a good lesson in reg expressions.

I also got round the problem with this code:

```
filter: function(t){ if (t.tweet_raw_text.indexOf("#EF1") !== -1; },
```

Answer (score 2):

First let's break down the regular expression you have to see how it works.

`/^@\w+/` - The slashes (`/`) at the beginning and end are just delimiters that tell JavaScript that this is a regular expression.

`^` - matches the beginning of a string.
`@` - matches the literal @ symbol.
`\w` - matches any alphanumeric character including underscore (short for `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`).
`+` - is short for `{1,}`. Matches the previous character or expression (`\w`) one or more times.

That's how you match a tweet that starts with the `@` symbol.  To match a tweet that contains a specific hashtag, you can replace the regular expression above with the specific hashtag you're trying to match.

For example, `/#StackOverflow/.test(t.tweet_raw_text);` will match a tweet that contains the exact hashtag `#StackOverflow`.  That's a case-sensitive pattern though, so it wouldn't match the hashtag `#stackoverflow`.  To make a JavaScript regular expression case insensitive, just add the `i` modifier after the closing delimeter like so:  `/#StackOverflow/i`.